# how to adjust table row for email signature in HTML

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm building a email signature and have trouble on showing in my email in Outlook. Basically my code had not contained any space or something like that but unfortunately it happened with me.

Here how It's supposed to look:
[image]

and here how it's turning out on this:
[image]

actually i need to remove unwanted space from there but i don't know how
here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>saddam</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (saddam.png) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1000" height="332" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/5ypGq46F/saddam-01.gif" width="254" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QxxvNTyg/saddam-02.gif" width="72" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T3BscHYQ/saddam-03.gif" width="86" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9F8KDQ66/saddam-04.gif" width="96" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/05CLqfc2/saddam-05.gif" width="86" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/t4sfWHyY/saddam-06.gif" width="86" height="149" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FzFCKMDF/saddam-07.gif" width="320" height="149" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/26DXsbWZ/saddam-08.gif" width="254" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MYNCmPN/saddam-09.gif" width="72" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tRDmcg4s/saddam-10.gif" width="86" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4y8LHWS6/saddam-11.gif" width="96" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7Y6Qry5m/saddam-12.gif" width="86" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vHN2QS9M/saddam-13.gif" width="86" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CxnPdHH8/saddam-14.gif" width="320" height="30" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/g09MhXNT/saddam-15.gif" width="254" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9MCJ833P/saddam-16.gif" width="72" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PqmSQX7r/saddam-17.gif" width="86" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kGhsgB2w/saddam-18.gif" width="96" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50gpDP1h/saddam-19.gif" width="86" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vTmXyWZc/saddam-20.gif" width="86" height="75" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Kc9JNs0L/saddam-21.gif" width="320" height="75" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tCYDmtcc/saddam-22.gif" width="254" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DyH5V4kw/saddam-23.gif" width="72" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DwG67fnd/saddam-24.gif" width="86" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/25fwyp5p/saddam-25.gif" width="96" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/xdyPbskX/saddam-26.gif" width="86" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/SsSfLW8D/saddam-27.gif" width="86" height="78" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0QVdVb0x/saddam-28.gif" width="320" height="78" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you have a simple link to your business card page. If you sent me 3 emails, my inbox would be full and my data plan depleted

Comment: i am totally new here and i don't know how can i give u that link specifically